# how to use reduce function of java 8 to calculate average

Tags: java, java-8

I was studying `java 8` concepts. I came across `reduce` method of `stream` api. On some tutorial I found that there are some inbuilt `reduce` methods available to do certain job like `sum` `average` etc.

I don't want to use those inbuilt methods so that I can understand how actually does the `reduce` method works.

From a list of employees I wanted to calculate average salary of those employees which have grade A.

So I wrote below code which have both classic java code and java 8 code. I want to know, how can I use `reduce` method instead of built in method like `average`.

**Code:**

```
class TestReduce{
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    private class Employee{
        int id;
        String name;
        String grade;
        double salary;
    }
    private static List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        List<Employee> list = Stream.of(
                new TestReduce().new Employee(101, "mango", "A", 60000.0),
                new TestReduce().new Employee(102, "apple", "B", 15000.0),
                new TestReduce().new Employee(103, "carrot", "C", 10000.0),
                new TestReduce().new Employee(104, "reddish", "A", 70000.0),
                new TestReduce().new Employee(105, "potato", "B", 20000.0),
                new TestReduce().new Employee(106, "okra", "C", 15000.0),
                new TestReduce().new Employee(107, "tomato", "A", 80000.0)
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return list;
    }
    
    static void test0() {
        List<Employee> list = getEmployees();
        double sum = 0.0;
        int count = 0;
        for(Employee emp:list) {
            if(emp.getGrade().equals("A")) {
                count++;
                sum = sum+emp.getSalary();
            }
        }
        

System.out.println("CLASSIC approach: average salary is grade A employees : "+sum/count);


        double avg =  getEmployees().stream()
.filter(emp->emp.getGrade().equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
.map(emp->emp.getSalary())
.mapToDouble(i->i)
.average()
.getAsDouble();
        

System.out.println("JAVA 8 approach: average salary is grade A employees : "+avg);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could start by reading [the Java Tutorial on reductions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html).

Comment: The only thing you can do if you want to practise reduction is to get the sum of the employees' salary. Then you can calculate the average from that

Comment: BTW Java 8 is pretty old... in not-so-old versions of Java there are a bunch of `List.of()` methods to create an (unmodifiable) list; no need to use a `Stream`; and even if that is wanted, `Stream.toList()` can be used to avoid using a `Collector`. If you cannot make the `Employee` class `static`, create one single instance of `TestReduce` to be uswed for all the `Employee` instances

Comment: BTW-2: can't `.map(emp->emp.getSalary()).mapToDouble(i->i)` be expressed as `.mapToDouble(emp->emp.getSalary())` or  `.mapToDouble(Employee::getSalary)` (avoiding unnecessary boxing/unboxing)

Answer (score 2):

> how can I use `reduce` method instead of built in method like `average`.

This particular case is somewhat tricky, because to average, you need to accumulate two different values at the same time, and then combine those at the end.  Java's generic `Stream.reduce()` and `DoubleStream.reduce()` methods don't directly support that.

But you can reduce your stream to a two-element List or array containing the element count and sum, then compute the average after.  Or you could make that a little more fluent by introducing a custom class into which to aggregate the result.  For example:

```
static class Averager {
    private long elementCount = 0;
    private double elementSum = 0.0;

    public double getAverage() {
        return elementCount == 0 ? Double.NaN : elementSum / elementCount;
    }

    public static Averager ofOneElement(double d) {
        Averager a = new Averager();
        a.elementCount = 1;
        a.elementSum = d;
        return a;
    }

    public static Averager combine(Averager a, Averager b) {
        Averager c = new Averager();
        c.elementCount = a.elementCount + b.elementCount;
        c.elementSum = a.elementSum + b.elementSum;
        return c;
    }
}

// ... the actual reduction:

        double avg =  getEmployees().stream()
            .filter(emp->emp.getGrade().equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
            .map(emp -> Averager.ofOneElement(emp.getSalary()))
            .reduce(new Averager(), Averager::combine)
            .getAverage();
```

Of course, that's a lot more *verbose* than the built-in `average()` reduction of `DoubleStream`, but that's to be expected.

Comment: You can get rid of the `map` operation by using https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator). You'd need to replace `ofOneElement` with non-static `addElement(double d)` that adds a single element, and use this as the accumulator.

Comment: Agreed, @RobSpoor.  Had I recognized that when I wrote this answer, I probably would have done it that way, but at this point I'm going to rely on your comment to highlight that alternative.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the answer from John, you could use the `collect()` method, the alternative generic reduction method (see the [Stream documentation about Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction):

> A *reduction* operation (also called a *fold*) takes a sequence of input elements and combines them into a single summary result [...]. The streams classes have multiple forms of general reduction operations, called `reduce()` and `collect()`, as well as multiple specialized reduction forms such as sum(), max(), or count().

To use `collect()` the `Averager` class needs to be slightly modified (it is an accumlator of values and must modify itself instead of generating new instances), but looks very similar:

```
static class Averager {
    private long elementCount = 0;
    private double elementSum = 0.0;

    public double getAverage() {
        return elementCount == 0 ? Double.NaN : elementSum / elementCount;
    }

    public void addElement(double d) {
        elementSum += d;
        elementCount += 1;
    }

    public void combine(Averager r) {
        elementCount += r.elementCount;
        elementSum += r.elementSum;
    }
}
```

And the usage is

```
static void test3() {
    Averager acc = getEmployees().stream()
            .filter(emp->emp.getGrade().equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
            .mapToDouble(Employee::getSalary)
            .collect(Averager::new, Averager::addElement, Averager::combine);
    System.out.println("collect: average salary of grade A employees: " + acc.getAverage());
}
```